# What does [入]{はい}らなくなるからと mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

So the story is A brings home a cake to B and tells him to eat it however B responds with this

> だ、騙されんぞ。今は夕飯前だ。この時間は夕飯が**入らなくなるからと**、食べさせてくれないだろう？

What I don't get is the 入らなくなるからと.

Comment: need more context, what's the relationship between A and B ?

Comment: 「食べさせてくれない」っていったい

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 夕飯{ゆうめし}が入{はい}らなくなるから**と**

≒

> 『夕飯が入らなくなるから』**と**

In other words, the 「と」 is quotative.

≒

> 『夕飯が入らなくなるから』**と**言{い}って

or

> 『夕飯が入らなくなるから』**と**いう理由{りゆう}で

Even without knowing what this story is about, the meaning of the line is perfectly clear.

> "I won't be fooled.  It's just before dinner now.  You wouldn't normally let me eat anything around this time, saying I wouldn't be able to eat the dinner (if I ate something)."

「夕飯が入らなくなる」 literally means "dinner becomes unable to go into (me/my stomach)."

Thus, I used "I wouldn't be able to eat the dinner" in my own translation.

Seems like the speaker does not trust Person A and/or the cake.

Answer (score 1):

I think it goes like this:

騙されん  =  騙されない  "will not be tricked"

入らない  is  いらない , meaning  "does not need" , i.e. "will not want", properly written either with hiragana or with the  kanji  要:  要らない . So  いらなくなる , "it will become that I do not want" means "I shall cease to want", "I shall lose my desire for", and いらなくなるから =  "because I shall not want".   と is the "quotative と "  and からと  means "stating that it is because", "giving the reason that", "on the grounds that".

A literalish version would go:

"I shall not be deceived. Now is [just] before dinner time. At this time [he/she/you/they/somebody] won't let me eat it on the grounds that I shall cease to want my dinner - isn't that right?".

As a somewhat more natural version, I'd suggest:

"You won't catch me out. It's nearly dinner time, and [whoever-it-is] wouldn't let me eat it now because they'd say it would spoil my appetite for dinner - right?"

Note in passing the difference between   から, meaning "because", "for the true or valid reason that", and  からといって "on the false or spurious grounds that".

Comment: +1 for most of it, but I'm confused how you ended up turning 入らない into 要らない

Comment: In Classical Japanese (文語 ) the verb "enter" was  いる , written  入る. This form survives in a few words , such as 入口 (いりぐち） and  立入禁止 (たちいりきんし). The modern  はいる  was, historically, a compound of  這う  (はう) , meaning  "crawl", and   いる , "enter". It was written, until the post-war reforms in orthography, as  這入る . Now, はいる  is written  入る , but computers still offer this as a way of writing いる , so it's easy to use it by mistake (or out of ignorance) for other verbs that have the dictionary form  いる , such as 居る ,"be [in a place]", 鋳る,   "forge",  射る , "shoot [an arrow]",  炒る , "roast", etc.